# Is it possible to have a gRPC Server act as a Client aswell? C#

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm working on a gRPC service the service needs to be able to sync between multiple instances of its self, I have a plan to do this but i can't figure out how to configure the C# project file to allow me to use both the Client and Server files without generating two copies of the files.

Is it possible?

Comment: Assuming you're using the protoc plugin, the generator creates both server and client stubs - so you only need to generate them once. It's not really clear what problem you're facing, or how you're configuring the generator.

Comment: If you are using Grpc.Tools to generate the code, look at the docs https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/BUILD-INTEGRATION.md#protobuf-item-metadata-reference (GrpcServices = none, client, server or "both"). "both" is the default.